In this video, does that air gap between the ball and the layer of ice help break the ice? How?
Towards the end of the video,
The very cold ball dipped in water was hammered to get rid of the ice that formed around it.
It is also mentioned that there was air bubble in between the layer of ice and the ball.
So, does the air bubble determine how easily the ice can be broken?
https://youtube.com/shorts/sNuIUSUB9uc?si=hJc18AtQgrukCYkw

If there were no air, a vacuum would be created, making it difficult to break the ice apart.
